# Vuetify: Dynamic SCSS styling based on selected theme

Tags: vuetify.js

I want the border of the v-select component to be black when light theme is activated (this works right now), and the border to be white when dark theme is activated (this does **not** work right now). How can I achieve this?

[image]

Code ([Playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn @click="toggleTheme">toggle theme</v-btn>
    <div>
      <v-select
        v-model="selected"
        class="d-inline-flex"
        variant="outlined"
        density="compact"
        :items="['Item1', 'Item2']"
        hide-details
      ></v-select>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

  const theme = useTheme()
  const selected = ref('Item1')

  function toggleTheme() {
    theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark ? 'light' : 'dark'
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  :deep() .v-field__overlay {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set border color from a Vuetify CSS variable that changes from black to white with the selected theme, for example `--v-theme-on-background`:

```css
:deep() .v-field__overlay {
  border: 1px solid rgb(var(--v-theme-on-background));
}
```

[updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)